# Is there any problem in this code while implementing ListView.builder()

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Why ListView.builder only showing 2 data, I have so many documents in cloud_firestore and I want to retrieve those data and show it in the ListView but exactly what is happening is it doesn't matter how many documents are there it is returning all the documents but when I am using ListView.builder  to show that data using widgets it is showing only 2 Widget.

```
 Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getData() async {
var firestore = Firestore.instance;
QuerySnapshot qn =
    await firestore.collection("LiveProducts").getDocuments();
return qn.documents;
```

}

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 295,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: SpinKitCircle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(91, 74, 127,10),
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              // title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["ProductName"]),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                // if (snapshot.data[index].data["live"] == true) {
                  print(snapshot.data.length);
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      height: 300,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      child: Center(child: Text('$index'),),
                    );
                // }
              },
            );
          }
        }));
```

}

One horrible thing is hapenning i am using Text Widget instead of Container Widget it is showing perfectly all the documents. like this

```
  return Center(child:Text(snapshot.data[index].data["ProductName"])),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)  {
            return ListView.builder(
              // title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["ProductName"]),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                // if (snapshot.data[index].data["live"] == true) {
                  print(snapshot.data.length);
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      height: 300,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      child: Center(child: Text('$index'),),
                    );
                // }
              },
            );
          }
```

> done → const ConnectionState
>
> Connected to a terminated asynchronous computation.

Comment: Same thing is happening

Comment: what does this   print(snapshot.data.length); give u

Comment: It is giving the correct data  whatever the data length is there

Comment: remove the  height: 300, and try it

Comment: Now it is showing the Widget but how to fix that height according to i have designed

Comment: why dont u use a column widget instead?

Comment: there is a more problem occurring list is not scrolling

Comment: Wrap the container with singlechildscrollview